# How to split this string in java

Tags: java, string, split

Hi in my program a string is generated like `"1&area_id=54&cid=3"`.First an integer and then a string `"&area_id="`,then antoher integer, and after that a string "&cid=" and then the final integer.These two strings are always same.But integer is changing.How to write split function so that i can find these three integers in three variable or with in an array.I can seperate these by looping but i want to use split function.Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How about

```
string.split("&\\w+=")
```

This works with your example:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.asList("1&area_id=54&cid=3".split("&\\w+=")));
```

outputs

```
[1, 54, 3]
```

The call to  `string.split("&\\w+=")` reads in English: Split `string` on every match for the regular expression parameter, and then return all substrings in between the matched tokens as an array.

The regular expression reads: Match all substrings starting with `"&"`, followed by at least (`"+"`) one word-character (`"\\w"`, i.e. letters, digits, and some special characters, such as the underscore from your example), followed by `"="`. For more details see the Javadoc for `java.util.regex.Pattern`

Comment: Thanks. I'm in a regex mood this morning ;-)

Comment: Thanks.It works.would you mind explaining a bit how it works.